# CORS vueJS y Laravel 7

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vue.js

Estoy haciendo una aplicación, la cual envía unos parámetros a otra web váa POST, estos datos son, el tipo de bono que vamos a contratar, quien los está contratando y el precio de este. Esto se envía como digo, a una web que es una pasarela de pago. Pero siempre me devuelve un problema con las CORS y ya no se que hacer, he intentado crear un middleware pero sin exito, he probado a poner el fragmento de código de "defaulfs.header" pero sin exito tampoco he intentado pasar el token y nada. También he probado a poner las cabeceras en el index.php de laravel, mismo problema... No se que hacer ya. Agradezco toda ayuda

Adjunto el código de mi petición actual, Como digo, en el controlador, me hace un redirect a una web externa con los datos proporcionados

```
let url = "/contrarBono30Min";
                    let bono = "Bono30Min";
                    axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
                    axios.post(url, { 
                                bono: bono,
                                token: csrf_token,
                                } 
                            )
```

**Controlador:**

```
public function contrarBono30MinHome(Request $request){
    $usuario = \Auth::user()->id;
    $bono = $request["bono"];

    $precioBono = \DB::select("SELECT precio FROM bonos WHERE codBono = '1'");


    return redirect('.....URL?bono='.$bono.'&user='.\Auth::user()->nombre.'&nif='.\Auth::user()->nif.'&precio='.$precioBono[0]->precio);
}
```

A parte. Cuando hago click en el boton para seleccionar el bono a comprar, tengo que hacer click dos veces para que aparezca el error o me envíe donde me tiene que enviar... No se porqué se está produciendo eso. Adjunto el código de mi botón.

**FUNCIÓN DEL BOTÓN**

```
contratar: function(){
            $(".contratar").on("click", function(e){

                var bono = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text();
                var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

                if(bono == 1){
                    let url = "/contrarBono30Min";
                    let bono = "Bono30Min";

                    axios({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: url,
                        data: {
                            bono
                        }
                    });
                }

                if(bono == 2){
                    let url = "/contrarBono1H";
                    axios.post(url, {bono:Bono1H})
                            .then((response) => {
                                console.log(response);
                            });
                }

                if(bono == 3){
                    let url = "/contrarBono5h";
                    axios.post(url, {bono:Bono5H})
                            .then((response) => {
                                console.log(response);
                            });
                }

                if(bono == 4){
                    let url = "/contrarBono10H";
                    axios.post(url, {bono:Bono10H})
                            .then((response) => {
                                console.log(response);
                            });
                }

                if(bono == 5){
                    let url = "/contrarBono24H";
                    axios.post(url, {bono:Bono24H})
                            .then((response) => {
                                console.log(response);
                            });
                }

            });
```

Comment: y exactamente cual es el exactamente el error que te esta mostrando?

Comment: @MiguelVargas gracias por tu respuesta: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://eintegra.es/pasarelaBonosSat?bono=&user=pepe&nif=45921676z&precio=20' (redirected from 'http://www.bonos.local/contrarBono30Min') from origin 'http://www.bonos.local' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

Comment: @MiguelVargas estoy intentando, que cuando haga click en el boton para seleccionar el bono que quiero, me envíe a la pasarela de pago que es otra web, totalmente a parte de esta aplicación, la cual ya he modificado para que reciba los parámetros oportunos, pero al intantar navegar a la pasarela, devuelve ese error

Comment: esas rutas estan mal, no deberias usar camelCase para escribir tus rutas, yo te recomendaria primero que coloces la ruta /contratar-bono y envias como parametro el bono y esos condicionales los usas en el controlador, estas usando vue?

Comment: @MiguelVargas en todas mis rutas siempre he usado camelCase y no ha habido problema, incluso en otros componentes de VUE uso camelCase y todo bien. El problema es al intentar redireccionar a la otra web. Si estoy usando VUE

Comment: mejor has lo siguiente, guarda la ruta de la url en una variable, la retornas y con javascript haces la redireccion.

Comment: @MiguelVargas vale, me parece buena solución. Pero quizás el problema es porque para que haga la función el botón tengo que hacer click, dos veces, sabrías porqué¿?? no he encontrado explicación a eso. ahora al hacer el return que me dices en la consola, me devuelve dos URL, la misma repetida, dos veces

Comment: no creo que sea eso, te esta pidiendo dos veces que hagas click, porque estas usando jquery dentro la funcion vue y eso esta mal, contratar: function(){ me imagino que lo estas asociando el evento :click de vue y luego con jquery le estas diciendo que haga de nuevo click, o usas vue o usas jquery, trata en lo posible de no combinarlos, quizas algunas cosas puntuales pero no en lo que respecta a eventos

Comment: @MiguelVargas solucionado. He hecho lo que me has dicho de retornar una URL en el controlado y con javascript hacer la redirección ha funcionado bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he solucionado como ha comentado Miguel Vargas

```
    $url = 'url?bono='.$bono.'&user='.\Auth::user()->nombre.'&nif='.\Auth::user()->nif.'&precio='.$precioBono[0]->precio;


    return $url;
```

y en vueJS hacemos la redirección:

```
window.location.replace(response.data);
```

Comment: lo que sucede es que estas usando axios y este tipo de peticiones no puedes utilizar redirect, se supone que este tipo de peticiones es para no tener que recargar la pagina, pudiste arreglar lo del evento click?

Comment: @Miguel Vargas si se quedó resuelto. Con el click, llamaba a la función y listo. Y lo que hice a parte fue pasarle por parámetro lo que necesitaba como el id

Comment: Esta bien, exitos!